# Laravel Forge | How to install Wordpress Database in Different Server

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, forge

I am a new user of Laravel Forge (LF), I just create 2 servers in Digital Ocean using LF, basically, the goal is to install Wordpress in one server and its database in another server.

So next time I create a new website, I just can install another Wordpress site but the database will directly use the aforementioned database server

Need your help on how to do such setup

Regards

Fajar

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: `So next time I create a new website, I just can install another Wordpress site` you do know wordpress stores what theme and what plugins you are using in the DB right?

Comment: Thanks @GaurangDave

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, I just learn how to make server setup using laravel forge, it's just a fresh installation of Wordpress